# Set SEND_TO_VOICEMAIL on Android contacts

Tags: android, android-contacts

I'm trying to modify the value of **SEND_TO_VOICEMAIL** from 0 to 1 and vice versa. 
I succeed to modify the others contact's details, such as name, number, nickname, email, ecc... but I need to change SEND_TO_VOICEMAIL.

I tried many possibility, but this should work... i guess:

```
        String rawContactId = "1";

        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
        ops.add(
            ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withSelection( Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + "=?" , new String[] { rawContactId })
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.SEND_TO_VOICEMAIL , 1)
            .build()
        );

        try {
            getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

but the logcat says:

> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(822): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no
>   such column: send_to_voicemail: , while compiling: UPDATE data SET
>   send_to_voicemail=? WHERE _id =?

I really don't know what to try anymore. Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the[manual, the SEND_TO_VOICEMAIL field you're looking for isn't in the ContactsContract.Data table but in the ContactsContract.Contacts table. It seems like you're trying to modify the wrong table.

See [ContactsContract.Data](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html) and [ContactsContract.Contacts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html) for the fields in each table.

Comment: Thank you, that's the answer! I just changed "ContactsContract.Data" to "ContactsContract.Contacts".

Comment: I have  problem on Samsung S3, anyone?

Comment: Will `SEND_TO_VOICEMAIL` flag work for incoming call? or do it work setting prior to incoming call?

Answer (score 2):

It is better modify through `ContentProvider` `Contacts.CONTENT_URI`:

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Contacts.CONTENT_URI)
    .withSelection(Contacts._ID + "=?", new String[]{hmout.get("cid").toString()})
    .withValue(Contacts.SEND_TO_VOICEMAIL, 1)
    .build());

try { 
    getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
} catch (Exception e) { 
    Log.e("Exception: ", e.getMessage()); 
}
```