# how to forward the calls to voice mail in android programmatically

Tags: android, phone-call, voicemail

I do not know how to forward the calls to voice mail programmatically in android ?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7298767/645270) help? (Editing a `SEND_TO_VOICEMAIL` value in a table)

Comment: If voice mail facility is active on device and after disconnecting the call, It will prompt calling user to leave voice mail.

Comment: how we can active voicemail programmatically

Comment: @AndroidRaji : Keyser is suggesting this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298767/set-send-to-voicemail-on-android-contacts link

Comment: are you asking how to activate voice mail or developing an app that will send a phone call straight to voice mail?

Comment: developing an app that will send a phone call straight to voice mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

Call forwarding is done by your carrier not by your phone, when the call reaches your phone its too late to forward it.

Comment: Android has a setting in People app that does it, so it must be possible.

Answer (score 2):

The selected answer is only correct if you want to limit your implementation to the Android public SDK.

It is possible to send a call to voice mail programmatically on Android.

While the phone is ringing, end the call. The call will be diverted to voice mail by the network. In GSM/WCDMA this is a feature called User Determined User Busy or UDUB, it also works on CDMA devices.

There are plenty of answers on SO on how to end a call on Android:

Using Java reflection and the iTelephony interface:

[End call in android programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065144/end-call-in-android-programmatically)
or
[end incoming call programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965702/end-incoming-call-programmatically)

== Update 2020 ==

Since Android P it is possible to hangup calls using the Android SDK - therefore forwarding to voicemail is now a supported feature of Android.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
    TelecomManager tcm = context.getSystemService(TelecomManager.class);
    if(tcm != null)
        tcm.endCall();
}
```

Add the necessary permission to `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission. ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS" />
```