# End call in android programmatically

Tags: android, phone-call

I see a lot of questions that it's impossible to end call programmatically in Android.
At the same time, I see a lot of dialer apps in googleplay market where you can activate the call and drop it also. How do they work?

**Edit**: I've read somewhere that my app has to be system app. Then how to make it system, and what is the difference between system and user apps?

Comment: As for me there is better [solutuion][1] to achive that.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977012/why-itelephony-aidl-works?lq=1

Comment: See http://android.stackexchange.com/q/27/440 for instructions about how to make an app a system app.

Comment: check this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47731725/how-to-end-an-incoming-call-programmatically-on-android-8-0-oreo/57356900#57356900

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You do not need to be a system app. First, create package `com.android.internal.telephony` in your project, and put this in a file called "`ITelephony.aidl`":

```
package com.android.internal.telephony; 

interface ITelephony {      

boolean endCall();     

void answerRingingCall();      

void silenceRinger(); 

}
```

*Once you have that, you can use this code to end a call:*

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
Class clazz = Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName());
Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
method.setAccessible(true);
ITelephony telephonyService = (ITelephony) method.invoke(telephonyManager);
telephonyService.endCall();
```

*You could use this inside a PhoneStateListener, for example. For this to work, you require permissions in manifest:*

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

*Edit: Apologies for horrible formatting, I still can't figure out how to properly do code blocks here :/*

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" /> cannot be used and without the above permission you cannot access TelephonyManager in runtime.

Comment: @VenomVendor I recall getting a warning along the lines of "not granting permission MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" in logcat while debugging, however it does not seem to be a problem, as the above code does work as expected on a variety of devices. Maybe the permission is not actually necessary?

Comment: @bgse : I am getting it as Error rather than warning.Is that because of minSdkVersion? i set it to 5.I am unable to add that permission in my application

Comment: @MAHANTESH This specific project was built with minSdkVersion="8" and targetSdkVersion="15". I just rechecked to confirm, it does compile and deploy without any issues. When the app is executed, it does produce a warning "Not granting permission MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" in logcat. That does not seem to affect functionality in any way though, so I guess that permission is not really required. Do you get the error at compile time, or at runtime?

Comment: @bgse: yeah i am getting a compile time error with minSdkVersion="8". even if it compiles then it should reject the call right?!?! if it is not granting permission then what is the use of having it?Basically i need to reject the call programatically.

Comment: This only works if minSdkVersion is 14 or less. If you set minSdkVersion to 15 or above, it stops working.

Comment: Can someone please explain this code? I cannot understand how its working

Comment: @WijaySharma This code used to work back in 2013, what it basically does is using [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful) to gain access to internal functionality of android telephony, which was not exposed publicly otherwise. A lot of the internals have changed since 2013, so this almost guaranteed does not work anymore (at least most likely not in the exact way shown here), from the top of my head I think Android 4.0.3 was still working, not sure about later versions.

Comment: you say create package `com.internal.android.telephony` but then you use different package (android <> internal) `package com.android.internal.telephony;` ??

Comment: @user924 It should be `com.android.internal.telephony`, thanks for pointing that out. Keep in mind that the approach shown in this post is mostly interesting for historical purposes and to get a rough idea, it is almost 5 years out of date and a lot of android internals changed since then.

Comment: @bgse I found other methods which works even for >= Marshmallow:)

Comment: @user924 Might not hurt to post your solution as an answer here in that case :-)

Comment: @user924 can you please share your solution that can work on oreo,Thanks

Comment: On a Nexus 5x with Android 8.1 and Security Patch form August I am experiencing that the app freezes completely when calling telephonyService.endCall(); This still worked a few weeks august, and it stil works on other devices with Android 8.0, I suppose the security patch changed this (still investigating).

Comment: @David What is the update from your investigation ?

Comment: @Pankaj none, I moved on.

Comment: Perhaps this might be of help for people around ;-) : https://github.com/anggrayudi/android-hidden-api

Answer (score 22):

For Android P (since Beta 2) and above, there is finally a formal API for endCall:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/TelecomManager#endCall()

The `ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS` permission is required in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS" />
```

With the permission, for API level 28 or above:

```
TelecomManager tm = (TelecomManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE);

if (tm != null) {
    boolean success = tm.endCall();
    // success == true if call was terminated.
}
```

At the same time the original `endCall()` method under `TelephonyManager` is now protected by `MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` permission, and can no longer be invoked by non-system Apps by reflection without the permission (otherwise a Security Exception will be triggered).

Comment: you gave very useful info, but how to handle this in Oreo? as there I m not getting endcall method.

Comment: @Panache see the accepted answer for Oreo or before regarding access to the hidden endcall method in TelephonyManager.

Comment: I get cannot resolve endCall mehod, I do have API 28 installed, any hints?

Comment: @David Do you have the `compileSdkVersion` set to 28 in `build.gradle`?

Comment: OMG, what a pitty! that was it!

Comment: What if a call is already running and a call that should be blocked comes in? How to manage this case?

Comment: @David calling this api should end the foreground call, i.e. the call that is ringing.

Comment: It has been officially deprecated in API level 29.

Comment: it is suggested to use - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/CallScreeningService.html. but can't find how to end a call with the help of call screening service.

Answer (score 3):

For Information.

May be of use in some situations. There is a potential workaround using the `InCallService` class. Most of the required information is here.https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/InCallService.html#onCallRemoved(android.telecom.Call)

It does require setting your app as the default phone app and ensuring the following is granted.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

If you implement your own class extending `InCallService` then when a call starts the call binds to your app and you get the call information through the `onCallAdded()` function. You can then simply `call.disconnect()` and the call will end.

Comment: Important: To use ICallService, you need to set your App as Default Phone App from Settings. Which means, now other apps wont get control when you have incoming call and you have to handle all calling functionalities in your app

Comment: I was looking for different solutions but nothing worked and found this. So simple and so useful. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Cut Call for the Api 28+

```
private void cutCall(){
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE }, PHONE_STATE);
}

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (requestCode == PHONE_STATE) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS }, ANSWER_CALLS);
        } else if (requestCode == ANSWER_CALLS) {
            cutTheCall;
        }
    }
}
```

//This code will work on Android N (Api 28 and Above)

```
private boolean cutTheCall() {
    TelecomManager telecomManager = (TelecomManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(TELECOM_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || telecomManager == null) {
        return false;
    }

    if (telecomManager.isInCall()) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            callDisconnected = telecomManager.endCall();
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This code requires api 26 and above. Make sure to add:     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS" />
in your manifest.

Answer (score 1):

`SilenceRinger()` does not work for android 2.3+ versions. Just comment it, other code will work fine.
Hope this works for you!

Answer (score 1):

Along with Adding android telephony interface and a broadcast receiver, you will also need to add android manifest receiver entry with the action `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE` for the reciever you want to handle intent.

You will get compile time error if you add

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE`
```

in your manifest file. But even if we remove this, it automatically rejects the incoming calls.

Comment: use <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
like this to avoid compilation or any other error

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isCallActive(Context context){
    AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    if(manager.getMode()==AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL || manager.getMode()==AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to @headuck's answer. For API 28, you also need to add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>
```

then request the permission in your activity. In total I requested these permissions to make it work (READ_PHONE_STATE, CALL_PHONE, ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS, READ_CONTACTS, READ_CALL_LOG)

Answer (score -1):

You can end calls using Telecom manager. I tested it and it worked.
You need permission ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS to do so. Even though it hints to answered calls I had it ending a call made from this phone. And this works for modern Androids.

```
   TelecomManager telecomManager = (TelecomManager) getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE);
```

telecomManager.endCall();