# Why ITelephony.aidl works?

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, aidl, telephonymanager

I saw some SO posts which discussed about how to end a phone call programmtically, for example, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065144/end-call-in-android-programatically). Yep, people focus on the result but no one actually explain the reason **why it works?**

I tried the code, it works well. But I would like to know more details about what is going on underneath? Why by creating the **ITelephony.aidl** , the android hidden internal `ITelephony` interface is exposed in our project? How does ourself created **ITelephony.aidl** & the automatically generated java (/gen/ITelephony.java) **link to** android's `ITelephony` interface? Is it only because of the name matching (package name & aidl file name)?

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
m.setAccessible(true);

//Why does the android internal ITelephony interface is exposed after created the ITelephony.aidl?
com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);
telephonyService.endCall();
```

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Actually, adding `ITelephony.aidl` to your project isn't necessary, it is just a convenience. You could just as well do it this way:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
m.setAccessible(true);
Object telephonyService = m.invoke(tm); // Get the internal ITelephony object
c = Class.forName(telephonyService.getClass().getName()); // Get its class
m = c.getDeclaredMethod("endCall"); // Get the "endCall()" method
m.setAccessible(true); // Make it accessible
m.invoke(telephonyService); // invoke endCall()
```

Under the covers this all works using Java reflection to access private (ie: not publicly documented) methods. You can figure out what methods are there, and what they do, by reading the open-source (ie: publicly available) Android source code. Once you know what is there and what it does, you can use reflection to get to it, even though it is "hidden".

The `TelephonyManager` class is implemented using a remote service. If you want to request the `TelephonyManager` to do something for you, you call a method on the `TelephonyManager` (that's the publicly documented part) and internally it makes a call to the remote telephony service to actually do the work. This is done using AIDL, which is a kind of "remote procedure call". The remote service can do things that aren't exposed publicly via the `TelephonyManager` class. What you are doing here is getting the client-side of the "remote procedure call" interface using `getITelephony()`. This returns an object of type `ITelephony`. This class has a method named `endCall()`. Once we have the object of type `ITelephony`, we can get its Class object and then get the method `endCall()` from the Class. Once we have the method, we make it accessible and than call it. The method `endCall()` is in the client-side of the remote procedure call. The method now sends a message to the telephony manager service (which is running in a remote server) and asks it to end the call.

Since the source code for the `ITelephony.aidl` is publicly available, you can put the source code in your project and your IDE will generate `ITelephony.java` (which contains the client-side of the remote procedure call) from `ITelephony.aidl`. You can then just `import` that and your IDE will now know about the `ITelephony` class and its methods. This allows the compiler to generate the correct byte-code when compiling your project. When you run this code on an Android device, you call in to the Android framework to get the `ITelephony` object and then you cast it to `com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony`. From then on, you can access the methods and fields of the object using the generated `ITelephony.java` as long as the Java code you have for `ITelephony` matches the actual class definition of the returned `ITelephony` object. If the class definitions don't match, the VM will throw an appropriate exception.

I hope this answers your question. I wasn't exactly sure how much you already knew about this, so maybe I mentioned stuff you already know. If so, sorry about that. If this isn't clear, please indicate what exactly you don't understand.

Comment: Is it just me or does this not work for Android 4.2.2

Comment: Fantastic, detailed answer.  Thanks.  Note: I don't believe the block call works after Android 4.0.3 because this API was removed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, adding ITelephony.aidl to your project isn't necessary, it is just a convenience. You could just as well do it this way:
[correct answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8R5ao.png)

Comment: Links can change or be removed in the future. Please include the key points from that link in your answer.