# Android: How to close InCallScreen of com.android.phone?

Tags: android, reflection, call, telephony

It is possible to [end a phone call programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977012/why-itelephony-aidl-works) without even using ITelephony.aidl.

But how can one close com.android.phone.InCallScreen that comes on top of the activity stack right after that?

It closes automatically after about 4 seconds, but I would like to close it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Sure it will work. It's working fine for me. Please try and let me know.

You could download the ITelephony.java file from [ITelephony.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/com/android/internal/telephony/ITelephony.java)

After that you add the method to end call:

**Function to Disconnect call**

```
public void disconnectCall(){
 try {

    String serviceManagerName = "android.os.ServiceManager";
    String serviceManagerNativeName = "android.os.ServiceManagerNative";
    String telephonyName = "com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony";
    Class<?> telephonyClass;
    Class<?> telephonyStubClass;
    Class<?> serviceManagerClass;
    Class<?> serviceManagerNativeClass;
    Method telephonyEndCall;
    Object telephonyObject;
    Object serviceManagerObject;
    telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephonyName);
    telephonyStubClass = telephonyClass.getClasses()[0];
    serviceManagerClass = Class.forName(serviceManagerName);
    serviceManagerNativeClass = Class.forName(serviceManagerNativeName);
    Method getService = // getDefaults[29];
    serviceManagerClass.getMethod("getService", String.class);
    Method tempInterfaceMethod = serviceManagerNativeClass.getMethod("asInterface", IBinder.class);
    Binder tmpBinder = new Binder();
    tmpBinder.attachInterface(null, "fake");
    serviceManagerObject = tempInterfaceMethod.invoke(null, tmpBinder);
    IBinder retbinder = (IBinder) getService.invoke(serviceManagerObject, "phone");
    Method serviceMethod = telephonyStubClass.getMethod("asInterface", IBinder.class);
    telephonyObject = serviceMethod.invoke(null, retbinder);
    telephonyEndCall = telephonyClass.getMethod("endCall");
    telephonyEndCall.invoke(telephonyObject);

  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.error(DialerActivity.this,
        "FATAL ERROR: could not connect to telephony subsystem");
    Log.error(DialerActivity.this, "Exception object: " + e); 
 }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't close the InCallScreen immediately. It hangs for a few seconds and then closes automatically after a few seconds, like in this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977012/why-itelephony-aidl-works

Comment: Ok I agree with you. I am using this one code only to end a call programmtically. If you found better solution please let me know. Thanks for your valuable information. Thanks