# How to terminate a phone call programmatically?

Tags: android, eclipse, telephonymanager

I'm developing an android app which calls a specific contact number, but I need to disconnect the call after some seconds automatically.

Even I need to wait until the above call get disconnected in my application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programatically answer/end a call in Android 4.1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481524/how-to-programatically-answer-end-a-call-in-android-4-1)

Comment: @shylendra: The OP probably wants to implement missed call feature. Call a number and cut it after x seconds.

Comment: @shylendra u guessed it wrongly.

Comment: my question is for an outgoing call not for incoming one

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977012/why-itelephony-aidl-works?lq=1) was the easiest solution I was able to find for ending a call programatically with a great explanation of it as well and here is an example of how you can end phone call after x seconds:

This would be an example of a method that you could call:

```
public void startDial(int milliseconds, string phoneNumber){

    //performs call
    if (!phoneNumber.equals("")) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + milliseconds, pi);

        Uri number = Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber);
        Intent dial = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, number);

        startActivity(dial, 0);
    }
}
```

And this would be an example of a Receiver you could set up:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        endCall(context);
    }

    public void endCall(Context context) {
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        try {
            Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
            Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
            m.setAccessible(true);
            Object telephonyService = m.invoke(tm);

            c = Class.forName(telephonyService.getClass().getName());
            m = c.getDeclaredMethod("endCall");
            m.setAccessible(true);
            m.invoke(telephonyService);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For API >= 26 (ANDROID_O)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS" />


requestPermissions(new String[] {
   Manifest.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS
 }, PERMISSION_RQUEST);

TelecomManager mgr = (TelecomManager) getSystemService(TELECOM_SERVICE);
mgr.endCall();
```