# How truecaller blocks incoming calls

Tags: android, android-permissions

Recently working on an Android project which required call blocking feature, I came to know that to block calls you need `MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` permission.

While the permission is only given to system apps, I am wondering how Truecaller does that. As far as I know, Truecaller isn't a system app.

***Truecaller background:*** It is an app widely used and known for identifying caller information. It has features such as blocking spammers and specific known and unknown contacts. Find more [here](https://www.truecaller.com/).

If Truecaller has special permissions, please mention the process of getting those if possible.

Comment: It might help if you start by explaining what the heck Truecaller is and what it does.  Its not a famous enough thing that you can just reference and expect us to know.

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: Hey @Astha, I didn't actually find any solution or you can say I stopped looking for one. Here is one answer that seems helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51085831/is-there-a-new-official-api-for-rejecting-calls-on-android.

Answer (score 3):

BroadcastReceiver

```
    <receiver  android:name=".CallBarring">
        <intent-filter  android:priority="100" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver
```

Which listen to incoming calls and calls `TelephonyManager.getITelephony().endCall()`

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

import com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony;

// Extend the class from BroadcastReceiver to listen when there is a incoming call
public class CallBarring extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    // This String will hold the incoming phone number
    private String number;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        // If, the received action is not a type of "Phone_State", ignore it
        if (!intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"))
            return;

            // Else, try to do some action
        else
        {
            // Fetch the number of incoming call
            number = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

            // Check, whether this is a member of "Black listed" phone numbers stored in the database
            if(MainActivity.blockList.contains(new Blacklist(number)))
            {
                // If yes, invoke the method
                disconnectPhoneItelephony(context);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    // Method to disconnect phone automatically and programmatically
    // Keep this method as it is
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    private void disconnectPhoneItelephony(Context context)
    {
        ITelephony telephonyService;
        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        try
        {
            Class c = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());
            Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
            m.setAccessible(true);
            telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(telephony);
            telephonyService.endCall();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Complete example [github](https://github.com/alameenkh7/call-Blocker-App)

BTW, `ITelephony.aidl` in your project isn't necessary, it is just a convenience, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18989160/2655092) answer.

Comment: Well, you did not specify the required version

Comment: It's not same. They don't end to call. Because caller hears still ringing tone on the phone..

Answer (score 0):

Since API 24 you can use the CallScreeningService:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/CallScreeningService
Not sure how TrueCaller did that before Nougat.