# Is there a new, official API for rejecting calls on Android?

Tags: phone-call, android-9.0-pie

### Background

For a very long time, there wasn't an official API for blocking calls on Android.

What developers did for CallerId and call-blocking apps, is to use some reflection tricks, as shown [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599443/how-to-hang-up-outgoing-call-in-android/8380418#8380418).

### The problem

It seems no blocking app works on Android P DP3 (tested on Pixel 2). Even very popular apps such as TrueCaller fail to block calls.

I believe this is because it might be replaced with an official API, as there are some articles that talk about built in call blocking capability for users:

https://www.gsmarena.com/android_p_may_introduce_stricter_call_blocking-news-29940.php

### What I've found

The only solution that could replace it, is by extending [**InCallService**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/InCallService) class, but by doing so you must also have your app become the default dialer app:

> In addition to implementing the InCallService API, you must also
>   declare an activity in your manifest which handles the
>   Intent.ACTION_DIAL intent.

Not only that, but only one app can be set as such at a time, so the user can't choose multiple callerId and/or call-blocking apps.

Seeing that I can't find an alternative, and that now it's the best time to request such a thing, I've also requested it [**here**](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110894924).

### The question

Is there another alternative for rejecting calls?

Does Google provide now with an official function to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be quite easy with the new Android P API. Your app needs to request the permission `Manifest.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS`. Then you can call the method `endCall` of `TelecomManager` class [doc here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/TelecomManager.html#endCall()).

Comment: Seems to work fine. Requires Android P , but that's when the problem starts anyway. Here's how to do it: stackoverflow.com/a/51121175/878126

Comment: However there isn't any ways on Android 8.0

Comment: @EricZhao There are, but they aren't official, so it doesn't work on all devices. You can see that indeed call-blocking apps fail to block calls on such devices.