# Is it possible to disconnect the phone call in Android 4.4.4 on Nexus 5

Tags: android, android-intent

http://www.emoticode.net/android-sdk/block-incoming-and-outgoing-phone-calls-programmatically.html

I used above link to get my code working, but I get compilation error saying package "com.XXX...." can not be found.

Googling, I also came across http://quia.cf/orange/pooxy4/nph-poxy.pl/es/20/http/stackoverflow.com/questions/20965702/end-incoming-call-programmatically=3frq=3d1

But I am not clear if a call that is already in progress, can be disconnected programmatically (my goal is to have an app, when opened should disconnect if a call is in progress; doesn't matter if it is outgoing or incoming call)

If so, can some one point me to  good working code (I understand java well, but weak on android).

Comment: possible duplicate of [End call in android programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065144/end-call-in-android-programmatically)

Comment: Also did you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481524/how-to-programatically-answer-end-a-call-in-android-4-1) approach?