# Block incoming calls vs a system service

Tags: android, telephonymanager, system-services

I wrote an application which has the capability of hanging up phone calls when they are received. In order to that I'm using the telephony manager and this permission is required:
android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE

However, this permission makes my app a system app and therefore I won't be able to place it in the play store later.
But I've seen apps in the play store that successfully block incoming calls ("Calls Blacklist" for example).
I wonder, does anyone know what API these apps are using in order to block an incoming call and also allow these apps in the play store ?

Thanks.

Comment: i think its API 8, not sure

Comment: I didn't ask for the API level. I m looking for the Android API/classes I can use in order to to that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of Broadcastreceiver class.
and also need to add this line in manifest to get persmission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE">
```

follow [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20210127130519/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/get-phone-state-when-someone-is-calling_22.html).

Make sure `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING` is only incoming call.
You cannot detect outgoing call state whether it is ringing or answered.
for outgoing there only two states:

```
TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE
&
TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK
```

Comment: What about blocking the call? My problem is hanging up the call, and I want my app to not be a system app.

Comment: create the service which in the background and in your CALL_STATE_RINGING write this code. ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065144/end-call-in-android-programmatically