# android - How to programmatically answer a call on android 6.0 ? [after applied the android security patch level 2016-11-01]

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, incoming-call, android-6.0.1-marshmallow

android - How to programmatically answer a call?

It is not running the 3rd party application that receiving a call after applying the Android security patch.

The link below can not be resolved.

=> [Answer Incoming Call in Android 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35438992/answer-incoming-call-in-android-6-0)

You need sample code to receive incoming calls.

help me.