# How to print only 4 values inside foreach loop?

Tags: php, laravel

There may be 5 or 6 values inside the foreach loop but i need to print suppose first 5 or 6 values.How do i do that?

```
<div class="tag-area">                         
        @foreach(explode(',',$product->tags) as $tag)                         
           <span>{{$tag}}</span>
        @endforeach                       
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try this:

```
<div class="tag-area">                         
  @foreach(explode(',',$product->tags) as $key => $tag) 
      @if($key <= 5)                        
           <span>{{$tag}}</span>
      @endif
  @endforeach                       
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will help you.

```
<div class="tag-area">                         
      @foreach(explode(',',$product->tags) as $key => $tag) 
          @if($key <= 5)                        
               <span>{{$tag}}</span>
          @endif
      @endforeach                       
     </div>
```

Comment: why posting duplicate answers? Also answer is already accepted. WHat is the diif bet your answer and *AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd* answer?

Comment: Same thing you have done on you previous answers also.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378607/what-permission-do-i-need-to-access-internet-from-an-android-application/45650001#45650001 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42339534/cant-answer-incoming-call-in-android-marshmallow-6-0/45649908#45649908

Answer (score 0):

If your key is numenric and its of indexed array you can directly do it like:

```
<div class="tag-area">                         
  @foreach(explode(',',$product->tags) as $key => $tag) 
      @if($key <= 5)                        
           <span>{{$tag}}</span>
      @else
        <?php break; ?>
      @endif
  @endforeach
```

OR try this;

```
<div class="tag-area">
<?php $cnt == 0; ?>
@foreach(explode(',',$product->tags) as $tag)
   <span>{{$tag}}</span>
   <?php
   $cnt++;
   if($cnt >= 5)
    break;
   ?>
@endforeach
```

Remember `break;` will stop unnecessary execution of loop

Comment: Since you're using "explode()", the keys will always be numeric :-)

Comment: Yes you are right.. @MagnusEriksson. But if OP want it for other foreach then its only suggestion for him :)

Answer (score 0):

if you have 10 element in array **no need to iterate after 4 iteration** so you should  break foreach iteration

```
<div class="tag-area">                         
    @foreach(explode(',',$product->tags) as $key=>$tag)
        @if($key >= 4)
            @break
        @endif
       <span>{{$tag}}</span>
    @endforeach                       
 </div>
```