# How can I accept incoming calls on Android 7 & Nougat?

Tags: android

I want to accept that I click on a button in Android 7, that is, API 24. I tried many things. But none of them worked on Android 7. I also saw that many developers have problems with this. Is there a clean result for this?

**I'm trying this. But this works up to Android 6. I need to accept incoming calls on Android 7.**

```
public void acceptedCall() {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("input keyevent " +
                            Integer.toString(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // Runtime.exec(String) had an I/O problem, try to fall back
                    String enforcedPerm = "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED";
                    Intent btnDown = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON).putExtra(
                            Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                                    KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
                    Intent btnUp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON).putExtra(
                            Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP,
                                    KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));

                    sendOrderedBroadcast(btnDown, enforcedPerm);
                    sendOrderedBroadcast(btnUp, enforcedPerm);
                }
            }

        }).start();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to accept calls on Android 7 for 2 days, and this was the only solution that worked.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45521447/11371302