# How to answer a call in Android starting API 24 and above?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-7.0-nougat, android-8.0-oreo

I can answer calls up to API Lollipop using this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38012714).
For Marshmallow, I just add a permission request for the user then the same code works as well.

However, starting API 24 it doesn't work!

How can I answer a call starting API 24 and above?