# Disconnect call programmatically in Android

Tags: android

How can we disconnect a call in Android. I know this has been asked many times. There are many other answers which state that our app needs to be a system app to disconnect a call but then the answer at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065144/end-call-in-android-programmatically) states that it is not so. But, even the answer there does not help to disconnect the call.

Then I saw that SDK 23 adds a new class `Call` which the Android document says can be used to handle calls. It has a function called `disconnect()`. So, how can this be used, if our app is not the dialer app? I only need the data to cut/answer the call. (Don't want to become the default dialer app, nor the system app) https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/Call.html#disconnect()

Could I be guided towards what is the latest information in this regard? For both Marshmallow and pre-Marshmallow devices. I feel the solution to both might be different.

Not sure of the solution for pre-Marshmallow, but for M+ I feel the `Call` class is to be used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [End call in android programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065144/end-call-in-android-programmatically)

Comment: @JimmyB That answer does not work anymore. Have you used it yourself? This is an important part of my app.

Comment: "does not work anymore" - Then please clarify in your question what your problem is. What does work? Are you looking for Marshmallow or pre-Marshmallow solutions?

Comment: @JimmyB Thanks. I have edited the question. Does it seem clear now? Please tell if otherwise. Cheers!