# How to dismiss a call during another call in Android 7.1?

Tags: java, android, android-7.1-nougat

I am using a broadcast receiver and i can detect an incoming call and dismiss it. I am trying to dismiss an incoming call that happens when i am already calling another phone using the same broadcast receiver.

Comment: Duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065144/end-call-in-android-programmatically

Comment: How is this duplicate? That question asks how to end a SINGLE call, I can already do that. What i ask is how to end a call that is ringing my phone when i am already talking to someone or i am in another call.