# Which API is used for end the call or cut the call in android version 23 to 27?

Tags: android

In android version 28 we used TelecomManager.endCall for cut the call and version 29 above we used callRedirection service and callScreeningService for cut the call. Then Which API is used for end the call or cut the call in android version 23 to 27?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18065415/1443981
This is the one you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use ITelephony interface concept.

Must use this format:
file name: ITelephony.java
file:

```
package com.android.internal.telephony; //must use this package only

public interface ITelephony {
    boolean endCall();
    void answerRingingCall();
    void silenceRinger();
}
```