# how to end on going call on android programatically

Tags: java, android

I am new to android programming .what I am trying to accomplish is start and end a phone call programmatically. for starting a dial I just followed [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-make-a-phone-call-from-an-android-application/) and everything work fine. But to end a call there is no full resource that explain everything .I find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065144/end-call-in-android-programmatically) discussion and I am bothering how to import the .idle interface to work for me. or if there is an alternative way to end the call

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // define objects for edit text and button
    EditText edittext;
    Button button;

    Button end;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Getting instance of edittext and button
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        end = findViewById(R.id.button3);
        edittext = findViewById(R.id.editText);

        // Attach set on click listener to the button for initiating intent
        button.setOnClickListener(arg -> {
            // getting phone number from edit text and changing it to String
            String phone_number = edittext.getText().toString();

            // Getting instance of Intent with action as ACTION_CALL
            Intent phone_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);

            // Set data of Intent through Uri by parsing phone number
            phone_intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone_number));

            // start Intent
            startActivity(phone_intent);
        });
        end.setOnClickListener(arg -> {
            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            Class clazz = null;
            try {
                clazz = Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName());
                Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
                method.setAccessible(true);
                ITelephony telephonyService = (ITelephony) method.invoke(telephonyManager);
                telephonyService.endCall();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

        });

    }
}
```