# How to end outgoing calls in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, sip, pjsip

I have a problem when I end the outgoing call, in the other side still ringing, I'm using this code to End the Call:

```
public void EndBtn(View view) {
    try {
        call.endCall();
    } catch (SipException se) {
    }
    call.close();
}
```

I'm using SIP protocol to develop my application, How can I end the ringing from the other side?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [end incoming call programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965702/end-incoming-call-programmatically)

Comment: I think this is a different problem, in my application I'm using SIP protocol (android.net.sip library).

Comment: Are you using pjsip?

Answer (score 0):

If you using pjsua (pjsip sample application) then call should be disconnected by this code..

```
        CallOpParam prm = new CallOpParam();
        prm.setStatusCode(pjsip_status_code.PJSIP_SC_DECLINE);
        try {
            Call.hangup(prm);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```