# How to end GSM call programmatically on Android 10

Tags: android, phone-call, android-10.0

We develop an Android app which is capable of ending a GSM call.
We used this solution for years:
[end incoming call programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965702/end-incoming-call-programmatically)

On Android 10 this solution unfortunately fails. 
I can't find any other solution which actually works on Android 10.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to stop GSM call on Android 10.
Next code is in Xamarin Android API level 27 using reflection.

First request for permission:

```
// Check permission AnswerPhoneCalls
if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(context, Android.Manifest.Permission.AnswerPhoneCalls) != (int)Permission.Granted)
        {
            activity?.RunOnUiThread(() =>
                ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(activity, new string[1] { Android.Manifest.Permission.AnswerPhoneCalls }, 0));
        }
```

Then stop GSM call by:

```
TelecomManager telecomManager = (TelecomManager)activity.GetSystemService(Context.TelecomService);
            var endcall = telecomManager.Class.GetDeclaredMethod("endCall");
            endcall.Accessible = true;
            endcall.Invoke(telecomManager);
```

Comment: Wont work in android 11 as reflection is blocked.

Comment: It works perfectly in Android 9! Thanks!

Comment: This still works on Xamarin.Android! Verified with targetAPI 32, running on Android 13 (Pixel)